# What is the Android ProcessKiller?

Tags: android, android-networking, android-file

Does anybody know about the ProcessKiller process on Android? It seems that it kills my App because it has an opened file. It happens when I am downloading a file to the SD card and then pull out the card during the download. That's what logcat says.

```
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
E/ProcessKiller( 2447): Process com.example.myapp (24090) has open file /storage/sda1/MyRecordings/81321226.recording/downloading/00000149.ts
```

I cannot properly close the file because it is a temporary file that I download and this happens when the user pulls out the sd card during a download. So I don't have access to the file anymore and because of this cannot close the FileOutputStream.

That's how I try to close the file after an IOException has been thrown (it throws an error as well). "fos" is a FileOutputStream:

```
finally         
{               
   try
   {
     Log.d(TAG, "Closing output file stream for file " + currentSegmentFile.getName());
    fos.flush();
    fos.getFD().sync();
    fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
       Log.d(TAG, "Error closing file " + e1.getLocalizedMessage());

       throw e1;
    }
}
```

So as I can't close the file and quickly afterwards the ProcessKiller comes up in Logcat and then the app crashes, I assume that ProcessKiller kills my app because of the open file. But what ProcessKiller is I cannot find more information. Or if I should close the output stream in another fashion I don't know as well.

If somebody has a suggestion, please share it. Thanks a lot!
Cheers

Comment: what about a finally clause ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: Android will indeed kill any process which holds an open file handle to the sdcard when the sdcard is unmounted.

Comment: Yes, I do use the finally clause. But it somehow cannot properly close the stream when the SD card is no more present.

@Chris Stratton: Thanks for this information! Do you have a reference to that?

Comment: It's been covered both here and on android-developers previously.  This used to be quite widely known, apparently the community is forgetting given that removable SD cards and USB Mass Storage mounting (the two causes) are less common today.

Comment: As I don't care if the data is completely written to the SD card, would it be a good solution to run a Service (in its own process) doing the write operation. If the SD card is unmounted, the process of the service is killed, but the process of the app not (so the app does not crash)?

Comment: @Dude have you finally found a solution for this? I have the same issue :/

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I have searched on android-developers blogspot and on stackoverflow, I've never found any topic related to this one: Have you some link that treat this issue? I just don't understand why there is any IOException (or some other exceptions) when a removable storage is unplugged.

Comment: There's no way to reliably handle a filesystem vanishing, so Android's cheap solution is to simply kill anything that could care.  If I recall there may be a warning broadcast or something (when the user indicates they want to unmount it, which is different from simply yanking it out), but ultimately if you open a file handle to a removable or unmountable storage, you are subject to death without warning - a fact you need to keep in mind in architectural decisions.

Comment: You might want to see the comments in the source (crrently around line 173, but that will change with time) at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/master/Process.cpp

Comment: @Kikiwa: I never found a clean solution to close the file. But I think the best solution would be, to let a Service do the file operations work. The service should be configured (in Manifest) to run in it's own process. So when the SD card is pulled and the process is killed, at least your app is still running because it runs in a different process and you can show an error to the user or do other actions. I didn't try this way out, but it should work best in my opinion.

Comment: @Dude & Chris Stratton: Thanks, I finally used a process that directly use "cp <src> <dest>" on my Android device instead of managing API's file descriptors. You can also create a dedicated Service with another Process in the Manifest, it works, but a lot more verbose :)

Comment: Thanks. I faced th same issue. And separating process for service is a good solution for this. +1 for this. :)

Comment: @Dude I have the same issue. Please let me know how you fixed that?

Comment: In my case app is killed even if my service is on a different process